# How to convert Python float array using ctypes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ctypes

I have neither experience in C++ nor in the ctypes library.

I have a program written in C with a DLL called `image_lib`. In the DLL header, the following function is defined

```
int Generate_Hologram(unsigned char *Array, unsigned char* WFC, float *x_spots, float *y_spots, float *z_spots, float *I_spots, int N_spots, int ApplyAffine);
```

In Python, I have my array called `x_spots` and some other arrays:

```
# coordinate locations
x_spots = np.arange(-1, 2, 1, dtype=float)
x_spots = np.arange(-1, 2, 1, dtype=float)
z_spots = np.arange([0] * num_tweezers.value, dtype=float)

# Intensities
int_spots = np.arange([1] * num_tweezers.value, dtype=float)

# Image for the GPU to compute the hologram on
Image = np.empty([width.value*height.value*bytpesPerPixel], np.uint8, 'C');

# Create a blank vector to hold the wavefront correction
WFC = np.empty([width.value*height.value*bytpesPerPixel], np.uint8, 'C');
```

I have (based on the single example the manufacturer gives)

```
image_lib.Generate_Hologram(Image.ctpyes.data_as(POINTER(c_ubyte)), WFC.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_ubyte)), ....
                           )
```

How do I pass x_floats to this function?
I guess

```
x_spots.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float))
```

Comment: It also depends on how you declared argtypes. You did not include that part of the code. Plus, I am pretty sure the code you included is not the real one, nor an extract (that would be ok, you are supposed to extract a minimal reproducible example ; that one may be minimal, but not reproducible) of the real code. Since `np.arange([0]*number)` cannot be real code.

Comment: Please add the missing code and output to the question. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal example to pass C `float` as a parameter using `numpy`.  It is an exercise for the OP to apply it to their function.  Note that the C function must assume a fixed size or be passed the length of the array in some form.

Also note that the `dtype` is declared as `ct.c_float` since Python `float` is typically 64-bit and C `float` is typically 32-bit.  Make sure the type sizes agree.

**test.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) // for Windows
void func(float* p, size_t size) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("p[%zu] = %f\n", i, p[i]);
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct
import numpy as np

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
# The helper function "ndpointer" can declare the expected type
# and either number of dimensions expected or the shape of the
# numpy array.  ctypes will then require that array and type check
# the parameter. 
dll.func.argtypes = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=ct.c_float, ndim=1),
dll.func.restype = None

x_spots = np.arange(-1, 2, 1, dtype=ct.c_float)
dll.func(x_spots, len(x_spots))
```

Output:

```
p[0] = -1.000000
p[1] = 0.000000
p[2] = 1.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem I can spot in your code is the size of your floats.

Note that it doesn't really matter as a pointer to what you pass pointers to your numpy data to your function. I, for one, am used to pass data as `arr.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p)`.

This is dynamic, so it is not like C compiler could check anything. And, at least in this case, there is no dynamic checking neither that in makes senses to consider this numpy array data as a pointer to this type.

So, saying correctly or not as POINTER to what you want to pass a numpy array to a function that expect a float * doesn't protect you against error.

It doesn't neither imply any conversion. The pointer is just passed to the C function, it is up to it to interpret correctly, and that has been done statically, when you typed the parameter `float *`.

So, it is not there (in the code you seem to be wondering about) that you can ensure that the C function get the bunch of `float` it expect. Whatever, the C function will get a pointer to the numpy data.

The problem you have in your code is that data in `x_spots` are not `float` (as in the C meaning of the word `float`; that is 32 bits floating point numbers). They are most likely double

I say "most likely" because I am not an expert in different python interpreters. I know that, depending on the interpreter, native `float` type of python may be `float32`, or `float64` or even something else. In the most classical CPython, they are `float64`. And I am not sure neither what it means for numpy when `dtypes`  is the native type `float`. But well, with my cpython, a `np.array([1,2,3], dtype=float)` is a numpy array made of `float64`. So, not 100% sure if that is a sure thing, or if it exists python interpreter in which that array would be made of `float32`. It is because I am unsure of that, that, anyway, I never ever use `float` as an argument for `dtype`. I use `np.float32` or `np.float64`.

But, well, most likely (or even surely) your `x_spots` is made of `float64`.

And then, it doesn't matter a pointer to what you say it is when you pass `x_spots.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(...))`, the pointer will be a pointer to those `float64`. That is, in C wording, to `double`. And your C function will treat it as a pointer to `float` (with no warning whatsoever: warning occur at compilation time, and we are past that).

So, long story. But conclusion is, either you

- Change your C function to accept `double *` as parameter for this `x_spots` thing. That's probably the best way, with your, probably 64 bits computer. But you seem to say that you can't really modify the C function
- So, alternatively, you can ensure that your data is made of `float` (in C meaning), that is create your `x_spots` with a `dtype=np.float32`.

Note that even if you choose the first case (`double *`), it would be better to change also dtype to explicitly set it to `np.float64`.

And once you have done that, it doesn't matter if you pass your argument as `x_spots.ctypes.data_as(c_void_p)`, as `x_spots.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_float))`, as `x_spots.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))`, or even `x_spots.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_char))`.

(I strongly encourage you, of course, not to use a false type as `POINTER()` arg, but that is for human readability of your code; from execution change point of view, it wouldn't change the result)

So tl;dr

- Change type of parameter of C function from `float *` to `double *`
- Or, change `dtype` of your numpy arrays from `float` to `np.float32`